# passing returned value from one function to another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I want to pass the value in variable lowest from `findMin()` to `printResult()` and display the value and the problem is that every time I add a number to the array that is lower than the previously added number it prints out `undefined`. what do I need to do to fix this. thanks.

```
var array = [];
function addGrade() { //when add button is clicked, the data in text field will be added to the array
var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
gradeArray.push(grade);
}

function findMin(array) {
var length = array.length;
var lowest = array[0];
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < lowest) {
        lowest = array[i];
    }
}
return lowest;
}

function printResult() {
var min = findMin(lowest);
document.getElementById("lowest").innerHTML = "Lowest: " + min; //min
}
```

Comment: You might already be aware of `Math.min(...array)` that does the job of your `findMin` function.

Comment: @JamieDixon hi! yes, I am aware of such function but for this case, I would like to use the for loop function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your findMin function accepts array type variable as an argument and your array is called "array" so your min variable should be:
`var min = findMin(array);`
instead of:
`var min = findMin(lowest);`